# C - Pointer - Am i understanding well?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to understand this type of variable: `char**`.

For me, `char**` is a pointer which is pointing to an address where I can find an array of pointers of type `char*` which are pointing to a addresses where I can found my string. Am I right?

Comment: ya!. Simply it is pointer to pointer to a character!

Comment: Not necessarily an *array* of pointers (although it *could* be) - all you can say is that it is just be a pointer to a pointer to a char.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost. `char**` by itself doesn't ensure that it's pointing to an *array* of `char*`. It may, or may not, depending on what your program does. Following the same logic, a `char*` often points to a string (a character array), but not necessarily.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) I understanding well now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

char** - is a pointer, which points to a pointer, which CAN point to a array, can point to a single variable, and can point to nothing.

Usually, two dimensional pointers useful with dynamic arrays, you can use like this

```
...
Point** SizeArray = new Point*[RowCount];
SizeArray[RowIndex] = new Point[ColCount];
...
SizeArray[CurrentRowIndex][CurrentColIndex] = Point(x,y);
...
for (UInt32 i = 0; i < RowCount; ++i)
   delete SizeArray[i]; // deletes an inner array of Points;
delete SizeArray;
...
```

Comment: `new` and `delete` are not really C-ish ;)

Comment: ok, you're right, but logic is all the same with malloc and free.

Comment: Thanks you for helping :) I wanted to do a dynamic array for a small project :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try [This](http://cdecl.org/) cute little site, and you will never have trouble understanding pointer-syntax again :-)

**NOTE:** I am not affilatied with cdecl.org in any way.

Comment: This website is very useful ! I'll put this in my bookmark ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. `char**` may point to an address where you can find a pointer of type `char*`, not necessarily an array. `char*` is pointing to an address where you can find variable of type `char`, not string.

Answer (score 0):

`char**` -> is pointer to pointer to a character. `char**` is a pointer to a `char *`, where `char *` may pointing to an array of character or can point to a character or may not!

when you allocate memory like this-

```
char **ptr;
int i;
ptr=(char **)malloc(2*sizeof(char *));
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
ptr=(char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
```

where `ptr` is a array of 2 `char *`, and each `char *` is pointing to array of 10 characters or string!